# Can't generate thumbnail images

Tags: functions, uploads, post-thumbnails, thumbnails, images

Having a very strange problem with this site I recently took over hosted on RackSpace. Seems whenever i upload a new image, it doesn't generate different sizes and I'm trying to get it where it will generate 160x160 thumbnails. I have that set in my Settings-->Media page on wp-admin and I checked functions.php on the theme like this:

```
// Load Language Text Domain
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'core_load_theme_textdomain');
function core_load_theme_textdomain(){
    load_theme_textdomain( THEME_SLUG, get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
    // - CL Custom Portfolio Thumbs
    if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
            set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions   
    } 
}
```

But when I check my wp-content/uploads folder....no thumbnails or any other sizes it seems but the original. Any ideas how to solve this?

Tried the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin too....no luck.

Comment: Checked the error log? You might have memory size issues, or permissions issues.

Comment: @AdamBell Did you resolve this? Please share the solution if so.